# Cannot immediately decode an object written to a file with bincode

Tags: rust

I am getting this exception when I try to run my test:

```
thread 'persistent_log::doc::test::test_sync' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: IoError(Error { repr: Os { code: 9, message: "Bad file descriptor" } })', ../src/libcore/result.rs:783
```

Term:

```
#[derive(Copy, Clone, Debug, Hash, PartialEq, Eq, PartialOrd, Ord,RustcEncodable,RustcDecodable)]
pub struct Term(u64);
```

Test:

```
fn create() {
    File::create(&"term");
}

#[test]
fn test_sync() {
    create();

    let mut f = File::open(&"term").unwrap();

    let term = Term(10);

    encode_into(&term, &mut f, SizeLimit::Infinite).unwrap();

    let decoded_term: Term = decode_from(&mut f, SizeLimit::Infinite).unwrap();

    assert_eq!(decoded_term, term);
}
```

I want to write the object `term` into a file and afterwards read it in.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[`File::open`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/fs/struct.File.html#method.open) opens a file in read-only mode, so writing to it will fail.

To open a file with read and write access, you must use [`OpenOptions`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/fs/struct.OpenOptions.html).

```
use std::fs::OpenOptions;

let file = OpenOptions::new()
            .read(true)
            .write(true)
            .create(true)
            .open("term");
```

> Great, but now I get a new exception:
>
> `thread 'persistent_log::doc::test::test_sync' panicked at 'called Result::unwrap() on an Err value: IoError(Error { repr: Custom(Custom { kind: UnexpectedEof, error: StringError("failed to fill whole buffer") }) })', ../src/libcore/result.rs:783`

After you've written bytes to the file, the file's cursor will be located at the end of the file. Before you try read from the file, you'll have to [seek](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/io/trait.Seek.html) back to the start of the file, otherwise you'll get this error.

```
file.seek(SeekFrom::Start(0));
```